# nth-of-type selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two sets of `ul>li` and I'm trying to get the second set of `ul>li` here is what i have done so far:

`div.subject ul:nth-of-type(1)` //it returns me both instead of one set

```
<div class="subject">
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="subject">
<ul>
<li>g</li>
<li>h</li>
<li>i</li>
<li>j</li>
<li>k</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can i get one set of `ul>li` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `ul` is the first of its type as a child of its own `div.subject` parent, so your selector selects both.

You should be able to do this instead, which will get you the `li` in just the second `ul`:

```
div.subject:nth-of-type(2) > ul > li
```

(Of course this will break if you have `div.subject`s mixed with `div`s that are not `.subject` and so on...)